Shows an unexpected URL in Vertx's failureHandler() to handle the failure in router context
I am trying to develop an application in Vertx web. When I configured the failureHandler() in router for handling failures in router, it shows a random url is failed(Example URLs: http://example.com:443example.com:443, http://www.baidu.com:443www.baidu.com:443, http://google.com:443google.com:443, http://karlshochschule.dekarlshochschule.de:443,http://api.ip.pnapi.ip.pn:443) with verb as CONNECT which is not used by me. I use Vertx 4.5.11 version for the development.
Can anyone advise me regarding this issue?
TIA

Perhaps someone tries to use your server as a proxy
